# Getting empty 'Ssl_cipher' with MySQLdb SSL connection to Amazon RDS

Tags: python, django, ssl, mysql-python, amazon-rds

I've just spent a week on the problems recorded in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315427/why-does-the-ca-information-need-to-be-in-a-tuple-for-mysqldb

Have now boiled it down to one problem. Here's a script that connects to the MySQL server I have on Amazon RDS:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb
ssl = ({'ca': '/home/James/Downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert-copy.pem'},)
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='db.doopdoop.eu-west-n.rds.amazonaws.com', user='user', passwd='pass', ssl=ssl)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_Cipher'")
print cursor.fetchone()
```

This gives me back `('Ssl_cipher', '')`, which I gather means the connection is not encrypted. Have also tried this using Django's `manage.py shell` function, and got the same result. Why, then, am I getting no exceptions? Data is flowing, certainly, but apparently the security is just being ignored. Any help on where I'm going wrong here would be appreciated.

I have tried updating MySQL-Python to 1.2.5 with no success.

Comment: What version of MySQLdb are you using? And what version of the MySQL client library are you using? MySQLdb.get_client_info() will tell you this. The ssl parameter should be a mapping, i.e. a dictionary.

Comment: MySQLdb.get_client_info() gives 5.5.35. This is MySQL-python 1.2.3 according to pip. And when I previously made the ssl parameter a dictionary (as in the other question [linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315427/why-does-the-ca-information-need-to-be-in-a-tuple-for-mysqldb)) it gave me this error: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation')`

Comment: I tested changing the ssl to a dictionary again and can confirm that exception still occurs with the line:
`ssl = {'ca': '/home/James/Downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert-copy.pem'}`

Comment: 1.2.3 may well be bugged with respect to SSL as it is very old. Please use at least 1.2.4 (1.2.5 preferred).

Comment: Okay. I just installed the dependencies Django wanted, but it's an old-ish version as well so maybe that explains it. Thanks, I will update and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: Another thing you might try is, using the `mysql` command line client with your option file, i.e. `mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/options.cnf` and see if that connects with SSL.

Comment: I have previously gotten it working using the command-line client with the same SSL cert via a command-line option but this is worth trying too.

Comment: I did `pip install MySQL-Python==1.2.5` but both the default_file script and my original script still return an empty Ssl_Cipher.

Comment: Did you verify that the command-line client with the same options file provides an SSL connection?

Comment: Yes, I did. `echo "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_Cipher'" | mysql --defaults-file=mysql_options.cfg` gives `Variable_name Value
Ssl_cipher AES256-SHA
`

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround for your issue: Use a default file. It will look something like this:

```
[mysql]
host = db.doopdoop.eu-west-n.rds.amazonaws.com
user = user
password = pass
ssl-ca = /home/James/Downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert-copy.pem
```

Then change your connect() call to:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(read_default_file=options_path)
```

where options_path is the path to the file above. This also keeps authentication data out of your code.

Django settings will look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know. I don't know how I could make it work with Django, unfortunately, and that is the main problem. MySQLdb just turned out to be the common denominator.

Comment: That configuration appears to work (in that it does not error out) but I still am getting the empty Ssl_Cipher value.

Comment: The Django solution is pretty simple: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: That does indeed look pretty simple. In fairness I hadn't looked at how that solution would work for Django because it didn't work for vanilla. If I get that solution you suggested in the comment on the question working with vanilla, I'll definitely make that change to improve security in the code.